# FreeBSD reboots during install and leaves invalid install

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox

I just downloaded the most recent FreeBSD CD image, and put it in VirtualBox. It looks like it installs fine but then it reboots and boots from the CD image again. When I make it boot from the hard-drive by pressing F12 at VirtualBox's boot splash screen and selecting the hard drive, it says:

```
gptboot: No /boot/loader on 0:ad(0p2)
gptboot: No /boot/kernel/kernel on 0:ad(0p2)

FreeBSD/x86 boot
Default: 0:ad(0p2)/boot/kernel/kernel
boot: _
```

What am I doing wrong?

Changing the chipset to ICH6 didn't work, increasing the RAM to 512 MB didn't work either.

PC-BSD doesn't work either (VirtualBox specific image)

Comment: Are using using the automated partition setup or manually creating the partiton(s)?

Comment: @Tim I am using the automated partition setup.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a VirtualBox related problem. I've seen a couple of posts that state changing the chipset or disk controller helped.

From [this forum post](http://forums.freebsd.org/showpost.php?s=57c5a36d6b486f0de037101ee4bc92d6&p=140535&postcount=4):

```
I changed the chipset in System to ICH6 and in Storage to ICH9 and it seems to be working now!
```

Comment: I can't find an option to change the storage to ICH9. Changing the chipset to ICH6 didn't work, increasing RAM to 512 MB didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with other operating systems at one time but it was related to what device VirtualBox rebooted to. This is a VirtualBox setting problem, not a FreeBSD one. When you reboot, does VirtualBox ask you which device to boot from?

Unfortunately, I'm not where I can look up where to find this.

Comment: _When you reboot, does VirtualBox ask you which device to boot from?_ No. It just boots from the CD image again.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall FreeBSD with VirtualBox defaults.

After the install, while it's rebooting, close the window and tell VB to power off the device.

Then go into the VB storage settings for this machine and change the boot order, making the *.vdi disk first.

Comment: I already said I tried booting directly from the disk, but then I get that error.

Comment: Yes, I saw what you wrote, but I had just finished grappling with an OpenBSD install and wasn't able to boot from the image until I manipulated the boot order. I just installed FBSD successfully into VB  and here's my gpart info: `$ gpart show 
=>      34  25992621  ada0  GPT  (12G)
        34       128     1  freebsd-boot  (64k)
       162  23068544     2  freebsd-ufs  (11G)
  23068706   1298432     3  freebsd-swap  (634M)
  24367138   1625517        - free -  (793M)`